# ValueError: Expected scalar shape, saw shape: (1,)

Tags: python

In gym when action is continuous (1,-1) i am facing above error. Kindly help me solve the error.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.action_space = spaces.Box(
        low=self.min_action, high=self.max_action, shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32
    )
    with summary_writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar('Stats/q_val', q_val, step=total_steps)
        tf.summary.scalar('Stats/action', action, step=total_steps)
        summary_writer.flush()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gym"? Can you provide more context for this code?

Comment: I don't have experience using the gym toolkit, but your error states that a scalar is expected while it receives `(1, )`, which means you probably are giving the wrong input to `shape` in line 3?

Comment: check the documentation of `spaces.Box(...)` e.g. by running `help(spaces.Box)` and look what the `shape` kwarg should be. Perhaps just `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it is the TensorBoard legacy issue due to the quick update of Google TensorFlow versions. For the newer TensorFlow 2.x, users need to have the correction as follows.

**1.Find out the directory of summary_v2.py**

For example, I have the following absolute path.

miniconda/lib/Python3.9/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/scalar/summary_v2.py

**2.Comment the line of code**

change the original line of code

```
tf.debugging.assert_scalar(data)
```

to the following code:

```
# tf.debugging.assert_scalar(data)
```

**3. Save the script of summary_v2.py**

And then run the script again and it will be no problem.

Please remember save the original script in case any problems.